# Android studio error after changing sdk path

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I have just changed my sdk path and got the following error:

**Error:Already created an SDK Loader with different SDK Path**

Previously it worked fine, the problem showed up after I have copied the sdk folder to my D drive. I am using 64 bit Windows 10 pro. I have changed the path in the local.properties file to exactly reflect the sdk path but there seems to be an error somewhere else. Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just closing `Android Studio` and opening it again fixed it. Didn't know it would be that easy.

Comment: The same thing happened to me and this was my solution also.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem in two ways you either change **local.properties** of your project file to exactly reflect the SDK path used by Android Studio, if that causes any problem for your project you can then change the default SDK used by Android Studio.
For an in depth solution check this [post](http://www.techiediaries.com/already-created-an-sdk-loader-with-different-sdk-path/)